# Reference footnote in a block statement

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

There is a footnote in a block statement that I would like to reference from outside the block. The following example throw an error for the `\footnotemark[\ref{hpb}]` statement.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{The Hungarian Phrasebook Sketch}
    My hovercraft is full of eels\footnote{\label{hpb}I will not buy this record, it is scratched.}
\end{block}
A so on, the pigeons went\footnotemark[\ref{hpb}]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Can you tell us what precisely the error is?  Also, it's not clear to me what you're asking.  Are you trying to reproduce the footnotemark in the text, or just reference the footnote number in the usual `\ref` way?

Comment: I'm trying to  reference the footnote number in the usual `\ref` way.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake in how I asked the question. I wanted to have another footnote outside the block statement that is a reference of the footnote inside the block.

Comment: So you want another footnote with the same number?

Comment: Yes, like using `\footnotemark[\ref{hpb}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The footnote can be references in the normal way, by `\ref` and the label which you put in the text of the footnote.

If you want the reference to appear like another footnote with the same number, don't use `\footnotemark`, which actually prints the *next* footnote number.  Instead, use `\textsuperscript` with the reference you want:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{Some Text}
        Now is the time\footnote{\label{fn}Hello} for all good
        men to come to the aid\footnote{\label{fnii}Again} of their party.
    \end{block}

    We see, in footnote \ref{fn} and footnote \ref{fnii},
    that...

     Or, we see\textsuperscript{\ref{fn}}
     that\textsuperscript{\ref{fnii}}...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

That will yield the following frame:

[image: Results]